# Orbits of the symmetry group of the cube?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $X$ denotes the set of corners of a cube and let $G$ denote the group of permutations of $X$ which correspond to rotations of the cube.

How can I show

-$G$ has just one orbit 
-if z is any corner then |$G_z$| =3 
- |$G$|=24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

-You can always find a rotation of a cube which takes any given vertex to any other given vertex.

-Draw a picture!

-Orbit stabilizer theorem.

Comment: How could $G$ have an orbit? Aren't vertices or faces of the cube that has orbits? Why would $\vert G_z\vert=3$, when we can take $z$ to 8 vertices of the cube, including itself? Confused, I am.